# SQL Server random using seed

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, random-seed

I want to add a column to my table with a random number using seed.
If I use RAND:

```
select *, RAND(5) as random_id from myTable
```

I get an equal value(0.943597390424144 for example) for all the rows, in the random_id column. I want this value to be different for every row - and that for every time I will pass it 0.5 value(for example), it would be the same values again(as seed should work...).

How can I do this?

(
For example, in PostrgreSql I can write

`SELECT setseed(0.5);
 SELECT  t.* , random() as random_id
    FROM myTable t`

And I will get different values in each row.
)

---

**Edit:**

After I saw the comments here, I have managed to work this out somehow - but it's not efficient at all.
If someone has an idea how to improve it - it will be great. If not - I will have to find another way.

I used the basic idea of the example in [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx).

**Creating a temporary table** with blank seed value:

```
select * into t_myTable  from (
select t.*, -1.00000000000000000 as seed
       from myTable t
       ) as temp
```

**Adding a random number** for each seed value, one row at a time(this is the bad part...):

```
USE CPatterns;
GO
DECLARE @seed float;
DECLARE @id int;
DECLARE VIEW_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
select id
from t_myTable t;
OPEN VIEW_CURSOR;
FETCH NEXT FROM VIEW_CURSOR
into @id;
set @seed = RAND(5);

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      set @seed = RAND();
         update t_myTable set seed = @seed where id = @id

      FETCH NEXT FROM VIEW_CURSOR
         into @id;

   END;
CLOSE VIEW_CURSOR;
DEALLOCATE VIEW_CURSOR;
GO
```

**Creating the view** using the seed value and ordering by it

```
create view my_view AS 
select row_number() OVER (ORDER BY seed, id) AS  source_id ,t.*
       from t_myTable t
```

Comment: AFIK you cannot emulate the behaviour of `setseed`, i.e. consistently produce the same random numbers, but to get a different random number for each row, rather than repeating the same one you can use `RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))` - e.g-  `SELECT RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) FROM sys.all_objects`

Comment: I recommend to go thru this link - http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-set-based-random-numbers/

Comment: @GarethD, I have to consistently produce the same random numbers - so I have posted an update, please take a look.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Your example uses `rand(0.5)`, but in SQL Server, `rand()` only takes an integer seed.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff... I'm sorry, I tried to be consistent with the PostgreSql example so I changed the value for the SQL Server as well. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in case it would someone someday, here's what I eventually did.

I'm generating the random seeded values in the server side(Java in my case), and then create a table with two columns: the id and the generated random_id.
Now I create the view as an `inner join` between the table and the original data.

The generated SQL looks something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE SEED_DATA(source_id INT PRIMARY KEY, random_id float NOT NULL);
select Rand(5); 
insert into SEED_DATA values(1,Rand());
insert into SEED_DATA values(2, Rand());
insert into SEED_DATA values(3, Rand());
.
.
.
insert into SEED_DATA values(1000000, Rand());
```

and

```
CREATE VIEW DATA_VIEW
as  
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY random_id, id) AS source_id,column1,column2,...
    FROM 
        ( select * from SEED_DATA tmp 
          inner join my_table i on tmp.source_id = i.id) TEMP
```

In addition, I create the random numbers in batches, 10,000 or so in each batch(may be higher), so it will not weigh heavily on the server side, and for each batch I insert it to the table in a separate execution.

All of that because I couldn't find a good way to do what I want purely in SQL. Updating row after row is really not efficient.

My own conclusion from this story is that SQL Server is sometimes really annoying...

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to get a repeatable random id in a table is to use `row_number()` or a fixed `id` on each row.  Let me assume that you have a column called `id` with a different value on each row.

The idea is just to use this as a seed:

```
select rand(id*1), as random_id
from mytable;
```

Note that the seed for the id is an integer and not a floating point number.  If you wanted a floating point seed, you could do something with `checksum()`:

```
select rand(checksum(id*0.5)) as random_id
. . .
```

If you are doing this for sampling (where you will say `random_id < 0.1` for a 10% sample for instance, then I often use modulo arithmetic on `row_number()`:

```
with t as (
      select t.* row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     )
select *
from t
where ((seqnum * 17 + 71) % 101) < 0.1
```

This returns about 10% of the numbers (okay, really 10/101).  And you can adjust the sample by fiddling with the constants.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I want to use the seed/random number for ordering. I tried the `select rand(id*1), as random_id
from mytable;`. but it doesn't help for ordering - because it appears that RAND(1) < RAND(2) < RAND(3) < ....
So it doesn't help for ordering, because the order is still the same...

Comment: @yishaiz . . . I had no idea that SQL Server was broken in this fashion.  Thank you very much for pointing this out.  The pseudo-random generator should work, at least.

Comment: the pseudo-random generator is not enough for me, so I have posted an update, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Someone sugested a similar query using newid() but I'm giving you the solution that works for me.

There's a workaround that involves newid() instead of rand, but it gives you the same result. You can execute it individually or as a column in a column. It will result in a random value per row rather than the same value for every row in the select statement.
If you need a random number from 0 - N, just change 100 for the desired number.

```
SELECT TOP 10 [Flag forca]
,1+ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 100 AS RANDOM_NEWID
,RAND() AS  RANDOM_RAND
FROM PAGSEGURO_WORK.dbo.jobSTM248_tmp_leitores_iso
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You could convert a random number from the seed:

```
rand(row_number over (order by ___, ___,___))
```

Then cast that as a varchar
, Then use the last 3 characters as another seed. 
That would give you a nice random value:

```
rand(right(cast(rand(row_number() over(x,y,x)) as varchar(15)), 3)
```