# Creating a UDF that will Accept Seeding for Rand()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2012

I am getting the follow error when trying to create the following function:

> Error 1   SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near 'RETURN    SELECT CAST( RAND(
>   @offset * @seed )* @max as int ) + 1'

What am I doing wrongly?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_RandomInt]( @offset int, @seed int, @max int )
RETURNS INT
AS
RETURN 
    SELECT CAST( RAND( @offset * @seed )* @max as int ) + 1
```

**Is it possible to create a UDF that will accept a SEED into the Rand() function?**

Comment: Regarding the syntax error see the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx#Scalar. Even if you fix that you will find other issues though. This is not possible.

Comment: what kind of work-around would you recommend?

Comment: do you not need the `begin` and `end` clause?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872332/sql-server-random-using-seed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the reason it wont work with this syntax which will give you this error.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_RandomInt]( @offset int, @seed int, @max int )
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @v_offset INT, @v_seed INT, @v_max INT, @result INT
    SELECT @result = CAST(RAND( @v_offset * @v_seed ) * @v_max as int ) + 1
    RETURN @result
END
```

It will give you this error - 
Msg 443, Level 16, State 1, Procedure RandFn, Line 7
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator ‘rand’ within a function

You can look here for help but you will need to do something different either way since you want to feed RAND() arguments, so the view idea wouldn't work.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/20/sql-server-using-rand-in-user-defined-functions-udf/

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax to create a function would be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_RandomInt]( @offset int, @seed int, @max int )
RETURNS INT
AS
begin
    RETURN  CAST( RAND( @offset * @seed )* @max as int ) + 1
end

GO
```

But then you're going to get the error:

> Msg 443, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fn_RandomInt, Line 5 Invalid use
>   of a side-effecting operator 'rand' within a function.

This is because you can't put indeterminate functions inside a UDF.  Your functions can use views or procedures that use indeterminate functions though for some reason, so you could create a stored procedure with an output variable that returns the value of the `rand` function and use it.  You could also just send the output of a `rand` function to the function and use it instead.  Like:

```
select dbo.fn_RandomInt(10, rand(@seed), 20)
```

Also, if you're trying to get your function to return a random number between @offset and @max, then your formula will not work.  You'd want something more like:

```
CAST(@offset +  RAND(@seed) * (@offset-@max+1) as int)
```